# Problems with CSS and Chrome

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My client looks great in Firefox but looks a little funky in Chrome :(

Here's some of my html code.. from the Inventory layout

```
<div class="clientinventory">
<div class="objtitle">
<p>Ore Inventory</p>
</div>
<div class="invitemvalue">10</div>
<div class="invitemtxtholder">Copper</div>
<div class="invitemvalue">0</div>
<div class="invitemtxtholder">Iron</div>
<div class="invitemvalue">0</div>
<div class="invitemtxtholder">Gold</div>
<div class="invitemvalue">0</div>
<div class="invitemtxtholder">Platnium</div>
</div>
```

Here's some of my css code.. from the Inventory layout

```
.invitemtxtholder {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #543C25;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: #FFF;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
.invitemvalue {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 65px;
}
```

**NOTE: I'm not allowed to post pictures apparently lol so heres the link**

http://www.ultimate-miner.com/UM2/Client.php

Comment: Define "funky"... what do you see and what did you expect?

Comment: What's the problem with the layout? Looks fine to me.

Comment: They look really similar to me in FF and Chrome, I have latest versions of both

Comment: goto www.ultimate-miner.com/UM2/Client.php

then

goto ultimate-miner.com/UM2/Client.php

Comment: Hm.. Am I the only one seeing the difference?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I can see a difference.

The Submit button jumps down in firefox but stays inline in chrome.

Add some width with css to the submit button and that will be fixed :)

Comment: I just double checked this, i cant see anymore things that should be different :)  Other than the submit button ofc ;)

Comment: Thanks :) I had a issue on my side with the browser not getting the newest css file...

All i did was CRTL + F5 to refresh page without cache and it worked :)